# How can I add a timer/stopwatch overlay to video?

Tags: software-rec, video-editing

I'd like to add stopwatch overlay with seconds counter to video file (in the middle, also insert some additional captions).

How can I easily achieve this?

Comment: TIP: if you use the words "time code" or Time-Code in searching for video time overlays you could be more sucessfull in searching. http://www.mediacollege.com/downloads/video/timecode/   timecodes are used in video to determine edit points and to sync 2 videos and all, and are more common than stopwatch. I dont know of any freeware yet that would do that. but there is chunks of video if the program will do an overlay/mix, it is a start.

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Comment: @slhck windows 7 x64 by default, but I can switch to Linux